# Slow page loading because of a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query running on a page to display records in a table with a foreach statement. It is causing the page to load slow, I think. I was thinking that the second line may be causing the issue. However if I remove the line `WHERE code = 'FE'` the page throws out a foreach error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
$arrquery = "SELECT * FROM phpvms_schedules 
WHERE code = 'FE'
AND locate(dayofweek(convert_tz(now(),'+1:00','+0:00'))-1,".TABLE_PREFIX."schedules.daysofweek)>0
AND phpvms_schedules.enabled = '1'
ORDER BY arrtime ASC";

$arrlist = DB::get_results($arrquery);
```

foreach:

```
foreach($arrlist as $flight)
```

Comment: Show us `EXPLAIN SELECT ....` and `EXPLAIN phpvms_schedules`

Comment: @Martin: `EXPLAIN phpvms_schedules` http://imgur.com/t9sWlwv

Answer (score 2):

This line of your query is probably causing you problems:

```
AND locate(dayofweek(convert_tz(now(),'+1:00','+0:00'))-1,".TABLE_PREFIX."schedules.daysofweek)>0
```

There is no way this WHERE condition can utilize an index, so there is no way you can optimize this query beyond having indexes on the columns used in the other WHERE conditions and the `ORDER BY` condition.

OK based on your comment I am updating my answer. I think you best bet is to use a string comparison, so in PHP build a string for the days you are interested in. So ,say you want any records that have days 0, 2, and 4.  You would build a string like this:

```
$day_search = '%0%2%4%';
```

Or if you have the days as an array:

```
$day_array = array(1,3,5);
$day_search = '%' . implode('%', $day_array) . '%';
```

And then you would do the search like this:

```
AND dayofweek LIKE '$day_search'
```

Of course you need an index on `dayofweek` as well as all other columns used in `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`, and `JOIN` conditions (though GROUP BY and JOIN don't apply here).

Honestly though, this table really should be normalized to have the days in a separate table.  That way each record could have an entry in the other table for each applicable days in you could query across a JOIN using a more appropriate WHERE condition such as `IN()`

Comment: Basically, if you look here http://imgur.com/t9sWlwv we're interested in the `daysofweek` field. I want it to be able to display just the records in a foreach statement by interpreting the value inside the field. i.e if the field contains following: 0123456, it will display records on them days (all week, 0 being a Sunday). If 24 being Tuesday and Thursday, it will display records from these days. I'm trying to exclude records that aren't relevant on the day.

Comment: Great Mike, thank you :) I'm just wondering, because the string will be dependant on the field, how do I tell the system to gain the data out of the `daysofweek` field instead telling it to look for `%0%2%4%`. Also, apologies for a silly question, but I've never indexed a field, how can I achieve this? ;'(

Comment: @zzwyb89 I am not sure what you mean by wanting to "gain the data" instead of searching against the string like `%0%2%4`.  Your `SELECT *` will still show you the value in the `daysofweek` field.  You need to look.  You should probably read up on indexes.  Here is the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html In that page it will link you to the `CREATE INDEX` documentation which is what you need.

Comment: I'll take a look, Mike. I mean that the data will be read from the `daysofweek` field, and not from a string. I don't know if I am doing this right because it returns a `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`: http://pastebin.com/xtj4jev6

Comment: @zzwyb89 In this suggestion you are comparing the data from the daysofweek field against the provided search string.  Before you try to work with any result set, you should verify that you got a valid result set from the DB and handle any DB errors. that way you can see exactly where errors you may be getting from MySQL.  You can also dump out your final query and run it against the database manually to see what result you get.

Answer (score 1):

don't remove the line `WHERE code = 'FE'` because it will fail the query, just remove the `code = 'FE' AND` condition, or remove the rest of the condition in the query as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident this will help you:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_code ON phpvms_schedules (code);
```

However posting the `EXPLAIN`'s I suggested in the comments will help us clarify

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you make the calculation in php and then inject it to the query